# React-Router v4 history on express server

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router, history

I have a react app using the following for router history.

```
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

<BrowserRouter history={history}>
...
```

This is served using Express server like this (server.js)...

```
//for build
// Serve the static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

This is working fine running locally and I can navigate to any Route successfully.
Once deployed to production, If I navigate to a Route, I get

```
Cannot GET /Sites/SiteDashboard/
```

The structure of my project is as follows which is a standard CRA install...

[image]

The problem I have is pointing to the correct location on the production build to point to the index.html (or whatever) so that I can access the history like I do running locally (npm start).

Can anyone advise where I need to point to.

Thanks.

Comment: I feel something wrong here. `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));` Can you do one thing? Can you try restarting the server and see?

Comment: Can you also try this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6161567

Comment: busy at the moment, will try soon. thanks.

Comment: ended up using HashRouter for now, which works 'out the box' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974369/hashrouter-vs-browserrouter

Comment: Great... Alright then.